# Using jQuery, display different text beneath the list, for each list item that is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, list, click

I have an unordered list, and I would like to show text describing each list item, as each list item is clicked. I am having trouble with getting the text to display correctly. Can you assist?

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <li class="item">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="one" class="selected">Description of Item 1</li>
    <li id="two" class="selected">Description of Item 2</li>
    <li id="three" class="selected">Description of Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>

$(".item").click(function() {
  $("li.selected").show('#id.li'));
});

</script>
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the text to display under each item that is selected, in a separate div. My jQuery is way off. I know I need a work-over on this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a custom data attribute to your list, so the items know which description belongs to which item.

When the DOM is ready we hide all descriptions. When an item is clicked, we hide all descriptions again and show the corresponding description for this item (identified by its `id`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("li.selected").hide(); // hide all descriptions

  $(".item").click(function() {
    $("li.selected").hide(); // hide all descriptions
    $("#" + $(this).data('desc')).show(); // show the description that belongs to the clicked item
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="item" data-desc="one">1</li>
    <li class="item" data-desc="two">2</li>
    <li class="item" data-desc="three">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="one" class="selected">Description of Item 1</li>
    <li id="two" class="selected">Description of Item 2</li>
    <li id="three" class="selected">Description of Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: plusOne  for comments.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
   <div>
      <ul>
        <li id="one" class="item">1</li>
        <li id="two" class="item">2</li>
        <li id="three" class="item">3</li>
      <ul>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul>
        <li id="_one" class="selected" style="display:none">Description of Item 1</li>
        <li id="_two" class="selected" style="display:none">Description of Item 2</li>
        <li id="_three" class="selected"style="display:none">Description of Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    $(".item").click(function(event) {
        var $desc = $("#_" + $(this).attr('id') );
        $('li.selected').hide();
        $desc.fadeIn();
    });
```

This should do the tick. you may wish to change how you handle ids etc as this is a pretty simple example.

working example https://jsfiddle.net/Mayhem50/yzcm2v59/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you forgot to close off your unordered list. I fixed that:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="item1">1</li>
    <li class="item2">2</li>
    <li class="item3">3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="one" class="selected" style="display:none">Description of Item 1</li>
    <li id="two" class="selected" style="display:none">Description of Item 2</li>
    <li id="three" class="selected" style="display:none">Description of Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I adjusted it a little and went off of @Mayhem50 anwser with `display:none;`. But here is my jQuery answer which will also sufice unless you want me to make it so when you click one only that one shows and the other one doesn't.

Original:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item1").click(function() {
      $("#one").css("display", "inherit");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item2").click(function() {
      $("#two").css("display", "inherit");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item3").click(function() {
      $("#three").css("display", "inherit");
  });
});
```

Tell me if you want the adjusted version